# How to implement cost estimation for deferred computations with `flatMap`?

Tags: scala, monads

I have implemented a `Calculation` class that takes 2 parameters: a calculation input that is a call-by-name param and also a cost. When I try to `flatMap` calculations, the first part of it gets executed. Is it possible to defer everything in `flatMap` and still provide the total cost?

```
class Calculation[+R](input: => R, val cost: Int = 0) {
    def value: R = input

    def map[A](f: R => A): Calculation[A] =
        new Calculation(f(input), cost)

    def flatMap[A](f: R => Calculation[A]): Calculation[A] = {
        val step = f(input)
        new Calculation(step.value, cost + step.cost)
    }
}

object Rextester extends App {
    val f1 = new Calculation({
        println("F1")
        "F1"
    })

    val f2 = f1.flatMap(s => new Calculation({
        println("F2")
        s + " => F2"
    }))

    println(f2.cost)
}
```

Once `f2` is declared (`flatMap` is called), we can see that "F1" will be printed. The printed cost is `"15"`, which is correct, but I would like to have the actual calculation fully deferred, meaning that I shouldn't see the `f1` being executed when I calculate the cost.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez This won't do, since the step is `val step = f(input)`, this will evaluate the f1. I want to avoid that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your requirement

> defer everything in flatMap and still provide the total cost

correctly, then you want to compute an estimate for the total costs *before* making any computations. I don't see how this is supposed to work with the signature `flatMap[A](f: R => Calculation[A]): Calculation[A]` - your `cost` is attached to `Calculation[A]`, and your `Calculation[A]` depends on a concrete instance of `R`, so you cannot compute the cost before computing `R`.

---

#### Constant costs for computation steps

Here is a completely different proposal:

```
sealed trait Step[-A, +B] extends (A => B) { outer =>
  def estimatedCosts: Int

  def andThen[U >: B, C](next: Step[U, C]): Step[A, C] = new Step[A, C] {
    def apply(a: A): C = next(outer(a))
    def estimatedCosts = outer.estimatedCosts + next.estimatedCosts
  }

  def result(implicit u_is_a: Unit <:< A): B = this(u_is_a(()))
}

type Computation[+R] = Step[Unit, R]
```

The trait `Step` represents a computation step, for which the costs do not depend on the input. It's essentially just a `Function[A, B]` with an integer value attached to it. Your `Computation[R]` then becomes a special case, namely `Step[Unit, R]`.

Here is how you can use it:

```
val x = new Step[Unit, Int] {
  def apply(_u: Unit) = 42
  def estimatedCosts = 0
}

val mul = new Step[Int, Int] {
  def apply(i: Int) = {
    println("<computing> adding is easy")
    i + 58
  }
  def estimatedCosts = 10
}

val sqrt = new Step[Int, Double] {
  def apply(i: Int) = {
    println("<computing> finding square roots is difficult")
    math.sqrt(i)
  }
  def estimatedCosts = 50
}

val c: Computation[Double] = x andThen mul andThen sqrt

println("Estimated costs: " + c.estimatedCosts)
println("(nothing computed so far)")
println(c.result)
```

If you run it, you obtain:

```
Estimated costs: 60
(nothing computed so far)
<computing> adding is easy
<computing> finding square roots is difficult
10.0
```

What it does is the following:

- It starts with value `42`, adds `58` to it, and then computes the square root of the sum
- Addition is set to cost `10` units, square root costs `50`.
- It gives you the cost estimate of `60` units, without performing any computations.
- Only when you invoke `.result` does it compute the actual result `10.0`

Admittedly, it's not very useful for anything except very coarse order-of-magnitude estimates. It's so coarse that even using `Int`s barely makes any sense.

---

#### Non-constant costs per step

You can make your cost estimates more accurate by keeping track of a size estimate as follows:

```scala
trait Step[-A, +B] extends (A => B) {
  def outputSizeEstimate(inputSizeEstimate: Int): Int
  def costs(inputSizeEstimate: Int): Int
}


trait Computation[+R] { outer =>
  def result: R
  def resultSize: Int
  def estimatedCosts: Int

  def map[S](step: Step[R, S]): Computation[S] = new Computation[S] {
    def result: S = step(outer.result)
    def estimatedCosts: Int = outer.estimatedCosts + step.costs(outer.resultSize)
    def resultSize: Int = step.outputSizeEstimate(outer.resultSize)
  }
}

val x = new Computation[List[Int]] {
  def result = (0 to 10).toList
  def resultSize = 10
  def estimatedCosts = 10
}

val incrementEach = new Step[List[Int], List[Int]] {
  def outputSizeEstimate(inputSize: Int) = inputSize
  def apply(xs: List[Int]) = {
    println("incrementing...")
    xs.map(1.+)
  }
  def costs(inputSize: Int) = 3 * inputSize
}

val timesSelf = new Step[List[Int], List[(Int, Int)]] {
  def outputSizeEstimate(n: Int) = n * n
  def apply(xs: List[Int]) = {
    println("^2...")
    for (x <- xs; y <- xs) yield (x, y)
  }
  def costs(n: Int) = 5 * n * n
}

val addPairs = new Step[List[(Int, Int)], List[Int]] {
  def outputSizeEstimate(n: Int) = n
  def apply(xs: List[(Int, Int)]) = {
    println("adding...")
    xs.map{ case (a, b) => a + b }
  }
  def costs(n: Int) = 7 * n
}

val y = x map incrementEach map timesSelf map addPairs

println("Estimated costs (manually):      " + (10 + 30 + 500 + 700))
println("Estimated costs (automatically): " + y.estimatedCosts)
println("(nothing computed so far)")
println(y.result)
```

The output looks encouraging:

```
Estimated costs (manually):      1240
Estimated costs (automatically): 1240
(nothing computed so far)
incrementing...
^2...
adding...
List(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, ...[omitted]..., 20, 21, 22)
```

Note that the approach is not restricted to lists and integers: the size estimates can be arbitrarily complicated. For example, they could be dimensions of matrices or tensors. Actually, they don't have to be *sizes* at all. Those estimates could just as well contain any other kind of "static conservative estimates", like types or logical predicates.

---

#### Non-constant costs, using `Writer`

Using the `Writer` monad from Cats, we can express the same idea more succinctly by replacing the two methods `outputSizeEstimate` and `costs` on a `Step` by a single method that takes an `Int` and returns a `Writer[Int, Int]`:

- `Writer`s `.value` corresponds to size estimate for the output
- `Writer`s `.written` corresponds to costs of the step (which might depend on the input size)

Full code:

```
import cats.data.Writer
import cats.syntax.writer._
import cats.instances.int._

object EstimatingCosts extends App {
  type Costs = Int
  type Size = Int

  trait Step[-A, +B] extends (A => B) {
    def sizeWithCosts(inputSizeEstimate: Size): Writer[Costs, Size]
  }

  object Step {
    def apply[A, B]
      (sizeCosts: Size => (Size, Costs))
      (mapResult: A => B)
    : Step[A, B] = new Step[A, B] {
      def apply(a: A) = mapResult(a)
      def sizeWithCosts(s: Size) = { val (s2, c) = sizeCosts(s); Writer(c, s2) }
    }
  }

  trait Computation[+R] { outer =>
    def result: R
    def sizeWithCosts: Writer[Costs, Size]
    def size: Size = sizeWithCosts.value
    def costs: Costs = sizeWithCosts.written

    def map[S](step: Step[R, S]): Computation[S] = new Computation[S] {
      lazy val result: S = step(outer.result)
      lazy val sizeWithCosts = outer.sizeWithCosts.flatMap(step.sizeWithCosts)
    }
  }

  object Computation {
    def apply[A](initialSize: Size, initialCosts: Costs)(a: => A) = {
      new Computation[A] {
        lazy val result = a
        lazy val sizeWithCosts = Writer(initialCosts, initialSize)
      }
    }
  }

  val x = Computation(10, 10){ (0 to 10).toList }

  val incrementEach = Step(n => (n, 3 * n)){ (xs: List[Int]) => 
    println("incrementing...")
    xs.map(1.+)
  }

  val timesSelf = Step(n => (n * n, 5 * n * n)) { (xs: List[Int]) =>
    println("^2...")
    for (x <- xs; y <- xs) yield (x, y)
  }

  val addPairs = Step(n => (n, 7 * n)) { (xs: List[(Int, Int)]) =>
    println("adding...")
    xs.map{ case (a, b) => a + b }
  }

  val y = x map incrementEach map timesSelf map addPairs

  println("Estimated costs (manually):      " + (10 + 30 + 500 + 700))
  println("Estimated costs (automatically): " + y.costs)
  println("(nothing computed so far)")
  println(y.result)
}
```

The output stays exactly the same as in the previous section.

---

PS: I think I came up with a more concise way to summarize this entire answer:

> Use the product category of the ordinary ambient Scala category (types and functions) with the monoid of endomorphisms on object `Int` in the Kleisli category of `Writer[Int, ?]`.

In some hypothetical language, the answer might have been:

> Use `Sc * End{Kl(Writer[Int, ?])}[Int]`.

Comment: Great examples and explanation on different approach. This looks almost like what I need. The only requirement that I need to add is the refinement, since the costs depend on input size, e.g. input list size and so on. So I assume this will be only a matter of adding 3rd morphism, e.g. `def dates: Seq[Int]`, then the costs could be derived like; `def estimatedCosts; Int = dates.size * someCoefficient`

Comment: So, this answer should have been:  *"Use `Sc x End{Kl[Writer[(Int, |+|, 0), ?]}[Int]`."*, but unfortunately, this is not valid Scala syntax.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with haskell syntax. Any chance of translating the above into cats or scalaz constructs? I know those are 3rd party libs, but since I'm dvelving deeper into FP, I will most likely need them

Comment: @EduardasKazakas That's not Haskell syntax. I'm not sure this can be expressed in Scalaz or Cats either. I am not aware of any existing practical programming language in which something similar to the above one-liner would compile, it's purely hypothetical.

Comment: I see... Well, the proof of concept does what I want it to do and I will accept it as an answer. I wonder if it makes sense to change the above code into Scalaz constructs? What should be changed?

Comment: Glorious. I have tried this with Scalaz too, works the same. Thank you for a superb answer.

Answer (score 3):

You just need a little more laziness, so that the cost isn't eagerly evaluated in the `flatMap`:

```
class Calculation[+R](input: => R, c: => Int = 0) {
  def value: R = input
  lazy val cost: Int = c

  def map[A](f: R => A): Calculation[A] =
    new Calculation(f(input), cost)

  def flatMap[A](f: R => Calculation[A]): Calculation[A] = {
    lazy val step = f(value)
    new Calculation(step.value, cost + step.cost)
  }
}
```

Note that this still might not have exactly the semantics you want (e.g. calling `f2.value` twice in a row will results in both `F1` and `F2` being printed the first time, and only `F2` the second), but it does keep the side effect from occurring when `f2` is defined.

Comment: From the comments to other answers, it became clear that the OP wanted to obtain a cost estimate while completely deferring the computation, so I took the freedom to reword the question slightly (it was somewhat of an XY-problem).

Answer (score -1):

First of all there is no reason to re-invent your own `Functor` and `FlatMap` and I would strongly advice you to use existing implementation.

If you need deffered computation than `cats.Writer[Int, ?]` is your friend.

With its support you can write your cost as well as get functor and monad instances.

Let me give you an example. We start with some initial cost

```
val w = Writer.put("F1")(0)
w.flatMap(v => Writer.value(v + "F2"))
```

Comment: This isn't at all an answer to the question, and I'm not sure what `Writer` has to do with deferred computation.

Comment: @TravisBrown `Writer` itself does not, but if we require a context of `WriterT` to be `F[_] : Sync` we can suspend any computation in this context.

Comment: If the `cost` computed during the `flatMap` step depends on the concrete output of type `R` of all previous steps, then it's not possible to defer anything at all. I don't think the question makes sense. At least not with this signature of flatMap.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Well the question is: is it possible? So it does make sense to ask if this is possible to do. If it's not, then the answer is clear here... Maybe another signature then?